# How to make input cursor transparent or unwinking?

Tags: html, css, input, caret

I need to make an input caret unwinking or transparent. I know one way to make it transparent:

```
color: transparent;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000;
```

but I need another way.

Comment: Maybe it's useful to know why you need something else without text-shadow?

Answer (score 0):

```css
input[type="text"]{
    color : transparent;
    text-shadow : 0 0 0 #000;
}
input[type="text"]:focus{
    outline : none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="test message" />
```

Comment: Yes, it is working, but I need some solution without using `text-shadow`

Comment: <input type="text" style="color: transparent;text-shadow: 0 0 0 red;"/>

Comment: Maybe there is some css property which makes cursor unwinking?

Answer (score 0):

this will Works in iOS8.

```html
<input style="position: fixed; top: -1000px">
```